# This is a code for fetching data from json file I have tried

Tags: json

//  This is a code for fetching data from json file I have tried.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../json/my_json.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                contentType: 'json',
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                },
                error: function(status){
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: But this not working to fetch the json data from local .json file that is in another directory.

Comment: JSON does not work with local directories. You *need* a web server.